# DataContractSerializer Case Sensitivity

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I need to deserialize a raw xml to a particular object. However I am having issues when it comes to boolean and enum types, as case sensitivity is intact.

```
public MyObjectTypeDeserializeMethod(string rawXML)
{   
    DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyObjectType));   
    MyObjectType tempMyObject = null;

    try
    {
        // Use Memory Stream
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Use Stream Writer
            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
            {
                // Write and Flush
                streamWriter.Write(rawXML);
                streamWriter.Flush();

                // Read
                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                tempMyObject = (MyObjectType)serializer.ReadObject(memoryStream);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         throw e;
    }

    return tempMyObject;
}

public class MyObjectType
{
    public bool boolValue {get; set;}
    public MyEnumType enumValue {get; set;}
}
```

If the raw XML contains

```
<boolValue>true</boolValue>
```

it works fine. However it throws an exception whenever the value is different to the the previous, such as

```
<boolValue>True</boolValue>
```

How can this issue be solved in order to allow case insensitive boolean and enum values to be passed from the raw XML?

Comment: Preprocessing xml should solve your issue.

Comment: What do you mean by preprocessing?

Comment: Convert `True` to `true` by whatever means.

Comment: However there still remains the enum cases. If I have to preprocess these values I will be creating a less generic source code.

Comment: You can use generic approach for those. Get types with reflection, get possible combinations (`MyEnumType.MyValue` -> "myValue", "myvalue", etc.) and preprocess.

Comment: But still I have is a raw xml string. The serialization is done by the DataContractSerializer. How is it possible to point out the enums from a raw xml string?

Comment: [Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056.aspx) it. Or `string.Replace`. Or use regular expressions.

Comment: Can't you use XmlSerializer instead of DataContractSerializer?

Comment: You should get rid of that try/catch. It has no effect other than to make it look like the exception comes from the location of the throw.

Answer (score 1):

The [xml specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#boolean) *defines* xml to be case sensitive, and *defines* booleans to be the (note case) literals `true` and `false`. `DataContractSerializer` is doing it right. If the value is `True`, then *it isn't an xml boolean*, and should be treated as a `string`.

Comment: Yes - fix the sending software - it's broken.

Answer (score 1):

There are many way to resolve this. An simple way is this approach:

```
public class MyObjectType
{
  [XmlIgnore] public bool BoolValue;  // this is not mapping directly from the xml

  [XmlElement("boolValue")]
  public string BoolInternalValue  // this is mapping directly from the xml and assign the value to the BoolValue property
  {
      get { return BoolValue.ToString(); }
      set
      {
          bool.TryParse(value, out BoolValue);
      }
  }
  ...
```

and I use `XmlSerializer` for Deserialize the xml:

```
    public static T Deserialize<T>(string xmlContent)
    {
        T result;
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (TextReader textReader = new StringReader(xmlContent))
        {
            result = ((T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(textReader));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Using the XML Serializer is not a good alternative to using the Data Contract Serializer. It is much more limited, slower, and is almost unsupported.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I never say that XmlSerializer was better that DataContractSerializer, i just propose an solution.

Comment: The first code block was pretty useful for handling some enums with Mongo. I didn't need to write any deserialization-specific code, so I'm not sure how necessary, or even how valuable, the second code block is.

Comment: @Ellesedil The second code is a usefull method to deserialize any xml string to the specified type T. For example you can say: var a = Deserialize<MyObjectType>(xmlContent)